# How to run dependencies resolving process in background upon opening new project?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

When I open sbt project with Intellij Idea it stars a **long running** dependency resolving process that blocks UI.

[image]

Is there a way to just open a project and "put" dependency resolving process into background (like when I open maven project)?

Comment: I don't understand. IDEA will do this in background, so you can code. Does this block you or what?

Comment: So it somehow blocks UI or what? In my IDEA (13.1.2) resolving is done in background, just like for maven.

Comment: Yes it block ui. I mean resolving dependencies when you open sbt project **first time** in intellij idea.

Comment: @Cherry got it! (and even reproduced, as seen in newer version of question). Haven't tried it yet, but you probably can hit cancel and then, when project will be opened, invoke update, which will be done as usual, in background.

Comment: When I click *cancel* it blocks ui until it finish cancel operation. :(

Comment: But if wait some time (when sbt set another root - see messages) and press cancel it hold less time and open project window with background procces. But I do not think that this is stable solution.

Comment: I think this is field to improve in IDEA and you should put a issue on it http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL
Or it is needed by them to properly initialise project.

Comment: Run from console `sbt 'gen-idea no-classifiers'`. Then open the existing project. IDEA runs for you `sbt gen-idea` and tried to download sources and javadocs. See [sbt-gen Sources and javadocs](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) for more information